# empty strings after genfromtxt numpy

Tags: python, string, numpy

Thanks for your patience, as I'm pretty new to python.  The input file is a tab-delimited table.

```
import numpy as np
#from StringIO import StringIO

inputfile=raw_input('Filepath please: ')

fieldnames='Reference Position, Type, Length, Reference, Allele, Linkage, Zygosity, \
    Count, Coverage, Frequency, Hyper-allelic, Forward/reverse balance, Average quality, \
    Overlapping annotations, Coding region change, Amino acid change'
fieldtypes='int,str,int,str,str,str,str,int,int,float,str,float,float,str,str,str'

with open(inputfile) as f:
    storage=np.genfromtxt(f, skip_header=1, delimiter='\t', names=fieldnames, dtype=fieldtypes)

print storage
```

I get a ValueError: size of tuple must match number of fields.

Help?

---

EDIT:

### Well, after implementing @Wooble's suggestions, no more error…

EDIT2:

### But the problem now is that after I print storage, all the cells that are of dtype str are empty strings ('').  Why is this?

EDIT3:
I solved the empty string problem by changing the str types above to |S#, where # is an integer.

Comment: What's in the input file? (and, by the way, making a StringIO with the contents of a real file is... kind of silly. StringIO is for when you need a file-like object and don't have a real file.) And, further, don't `.close()` a file you opened in a context manager; the whole point is that the context manager closes it.

Comment: (Also, use `raw_input` rather than using `input` and telling the user to include quotes...)

Comment: Thanks for the help @Wooble.  I'm editing as per your suggestions.  Also, the input file is a tab-delimited txt table.

Comment: There are empty cells in the tab-delimited table… would that affect anything?

Comment: Aside: if you're working with named columns and mixed numeric and non-numeric data, you're probably going to have more luck with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) than with bare numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But the problem now is that after I print storage, all the cells that are of dtype str are empty strings (''). Why is this?

EDIT3: I solved the empty string problem by changing the str types above to |S#, where # is an integer.

EDIT4: See comment from Jinan Dangor below.

Comment: Could you please explain what integer you're referring to, here? Is it the maximum length of the string being read, or what?

Comment: fieldtypes='int,|S1,int,|S2,|S3, etc. etc. '     ...    Since this was so long ago, I'm not sure I remember, but this is my best guess.

Comment: Having figured this out, the number is the maximum length of the string being read. It isn't just consecutive numbering system. So '|S64' reads a string of up to 64 characters.